# Import a Python module when using WSGI

Tags: python, wsgi

I just installed WSGI on Apache to start using Python as a web programming language. I only added this line to my Apache config (except for the loading of the `mod_wsgi` module)

```
WSGIScriptAlias MyApp/ /path/to/app.wsgi
```

I have my `app.wsgi` running fine, but I want to use separate files for separate functionality. So, I created an `extras.py` in the same dir as `app.wsgi`, with not much in it:

```
class MyClass:
     pass
```

and put a

```
from extras import MyClass
```

on the top of my `app.wsgi`. But, unfortunately, I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name MyClass
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post your extras.py?

Comment: @HarshDattani updated question

Comment: also the `PYTHONPATH` maybe that could help

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI How would I get the apache server's `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: so can u show the mod_wsgi configuration that you created?

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI see update, I just put a `WSGIScriptAlias` directive in

Comment: use the `WSGIPythonPath` to point to the module

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI that was it, make it an answer, so I can accept it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `WSGIPythonPath` to specify the modules which are to be searched while running ur wsgi application.

more about it could be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath)